# Best way to define javascript associative array where keys are variables?

Tags: javascript, associative-array

To be more precise, lets say I need to define 50 different keys like:

```
myVar[myObj.something] = "something";
myVar[myObj.somethingElse] = "something else";
myVar[myObj.anotherThing] = "another thing";
...
myVar[myObj.lastThing] = "last thing";
```

So basically, I need to store bunch of strings in an array/object, with keys that are defined in another object.
Is there better solution than one above? Something like:

```
var myVar = {
   myObj.something : "something",
   ...
}
```

Comment: There are no associative arrays, so the best way would be to create an object !

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no easier way to do this. At least, not that I'm aware of...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see it different.

If the values are also in another object, then you could do something like `for(var key in myObj)` and then easily do `myVar[ myObj[key] ] = ???;`.

But the question is: what will you replace `???` with. So, if it's just the static strings associated to the different key, then your example is good enough I think, and you won't get anything notably much better than it.

Comment: Yeah, I need to place different static strings for values... So I guess there really isn't a better way to write it. Thanks.